Swapback issue with BEP20 contract
anothe rissue presents itself!
My problem is with the swapback function: (the function is public because i was testing it, it should be internal)
function swapBack() public swapping {
    uint256 amountToSwap = IBEP20(address(this)).balanceOf(address(this));
    require(amountToSwap > 0, "Nothing to swap");
    
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = address(this);
    path[1] = WBNB;

    uint256 balanceBefore = address(this).balance;

    router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        amountToSwap,
        0,
        path,
        address(this),
        block.timestamp
    );

    uint256 amountBNB = address(this).balance.sub(balanceBefore); // total

    // calculate relational dividends
    uint256 divTax = amountBNB.div(totalFee.sub(burnTax));
    
    // spread the pool costs relative to tax values
    uint256 amountBNBLiquidity = divTax.mul(liquidityFee);
    uint256 amountBNBMarketing = divTax.mul(marketingFee);
    uint256 amountBNBDev = divTax.mul(devFee);

    (bool tmpSuccess,) = payable(marketingFeeReceiver).call{value: amountBNBMarketing}("");
    (tmpSuccess,) = payable(devFeeReceiver).call{value: amountBNBDev}("");
    require(tmpSuccess, "Tax went unpaid to receivers");
    
    // Supress warning msg
    tmpSuccess = false;

    if(amountBNBLiquidity > 0){
        router.addLiquidityETH{value: amountBNBLiquidity}(
            address(this),
            amountBNBLiquidity,
            0,
            0,
            autoLiquidityReceiver,
            block.timestamp
        );
        emit AutoLiquify(amountBNBLiquidity, amountBNBLiquidity);
    }

}

the idea is that when the token amount reaches a certain threshold, the tokens that have been sent to the contract would be converted into busdT, and then split up to the accounts with their respective tax % amount defined here:
uint256 public liquidityFee    = 10;
uint256 public burnTax         = 10;
uint256 public marketingFee    = 5;
uint256 public devFee          = 5;
uint256 public totalFee        = marketingFee + liquidityFee + devFee + burnTax; // total 3%
uint256 public feeDenominator  = 1000;

but for some reason, the transaction fails with "Eip838ExecutionError: execution reverted: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED"
there is liquidity in the LP and there are tokens in the contract but for some reason it doesnt work. could someome please have a look and see what could be the issue?
thanks!

it looks like you might be missing an approval step before calling swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens. Try adding this line of code to approve the router to spend the tokens on behalf of the contract:
_approve(address(this), address(router), amountToSwap);

Incorporate this line before the swap function call in your swapBack function. This should resolve the "TRANSFER_FROM" error.
Please let me know if this works for you or if you have any other questions!

Thank you for your help, adding a similarly formulated line worked
